# Your APK's version code needs to be higher than XX in playstore developer console

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, build.gradle

Actually I am using cordova application, and for license verification purpose I have open the cordova app in android studio and https://github.com/javiersantos/PiracyChecker/ added this library like below in **build.gradle(Module:android)** file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))

compile project(':library')

// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Also **Androidmanifest.xml** file is

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="0.0.3"
package="com.html.codeplay.pro" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

**Followed steps are**

1) Already I have many application, so I know way of increase the version code and version name in **androidmanifest.xml** or **config.xml file**. Already I wrote above the Androidmanifest.xml. Here I can not able to find the **config.xml** file (I think that is only applicable for cordova application), because now I  load the whole cordova android folder to android studio.

2) I tried to write the version code and version name directly on the build.gradle file like below

```
defaultConfig {
    //versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
    applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

    if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
        minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
    }

versionCode 3
versionName "0.0.3"
}
```

**Final result**
When I upload this file in playstore it is always shown **Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 28.** Can you please suggest me any other way.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned:

> When I upload this file in playstore it is always shown Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 28.

You have already uploaded an APK with `versionCode 28`, you will need to increment your version code above 28 to be able to upload an update on Google Play Store.

If you have multiple modules, you need to make sure that you are setting the right version in your main module and not a small dependency lying around.

I would suggest you keep your version information in one place - either `AndroidManifest.xml` or `build.gradle`. Although `build.gradle` has a higher priority, so the value in `AndroidManifest.xml` will be ignored by Gradle while building your application.

Comment: Already I mention the details, I have entered the version code 38 but playstore does not detect it.

Comment: You can probably try using `aapt` or APK tool to cross check the actual version your APK is compiled with.

Comment: And make sure you are setting the right version in the main module of your application and not a dependency.

Comment: If I set VersionCode 1, google shown 18, versioncode 2, google shown 28. In that way only I given 3. Please give me more details about this.

Comment: That is not how it really is... there must be some confusion.